# Можно ли переопределить сериализатор JSONEncoder для стандартных типов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, json-encode

Можно ли как-нибудь переопределить поведение JSONEncoder для стандартных типов? Например, хочу, чтобы словарь сериализовывался не через `{}`, а через `<>`, чтобы строки не были обёрнуты в `"` и т.д. Причём, как-то особенно обрабатывать необходимо только **некоторые из** стандартных типов

---

Например, код:

```py
import json

print(json.dumps({"a": "5", "b": {"c": "d", "e": "f", "g": ["1", "2", 3]}}, indent=4))
```

Вывод:

```
{
    "a": "5",
    "b": {
        "c": "d",
        "e": "f",
        "g": [
            "1",
            "2",
            3
        ]
    }
}
```

Я же хочу получить:

```
<
    a: 5,
    b: <
        c: d,
        e: f,
        g: [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ]
    >
>
```

Необходимо получить данные именно в "кастомном" виде, десериализация не нужна.

---

Находил, как можно добавить сериализацию нестандартных типов, но как поменять поведение именно для стандартных типов (`dict`, `list`, `str`, `int`, `float`, `True`, `False`, `None`) не нашёл.

Comment: То, что вы хотите получить не является JSON, поэтому врядли вы найдете готовое решение. Можно попробовать адаптировать исходники модуля JSON под себя...

Comment: @MaxU Я понимаю. Немного некорректно сформулировал вопрос, но уже разобрался. Сейчас пишу ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Переопределять надо было методы `encode` и `iterencode` класса `JSONEncoder`.

---

Мой, очень костыльный вариант:

```py
import json


class CustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):  # Определяем собственный кодировщик
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.current_level = 0  # Текущий уровень отступа

    def encode(self, o):  # Как я понял, правило кодирования типов, кроме list и dict
        if isinstance(o, str):  # Наше правило кодирования строки
            return o  # Не оборачиваем в "
        else:  # Иначе кодируем правилом по умолчанию
            return super().encode(o)

    def iterencode(self, o, _one_shot=False):  # Правило кодирования list и dict
        if isinstance(o, dict):  # Наше правило кодирования словаря
            yield "<\n"  # Начинаем сериализацию словаря с <
            self.current_level += 1  # Увеличиваем текущий уровень отступа
            for key, val in o.items():
                yield "{indent}{key}{key_separator}{value}{item_separator}\n".format(
                    indent=" " * self.indent * self.current_level,  # Вычисляем отступ
                    key=self.encode(key),  # Кодируем ключ словаря по нашему правилу
                    key_separator=self.key_separator,
                    value=self.encode(val),  # Кодируем значение по ключу по нашему правилу
                    item_separator=self.item_separator
                )
            self.current_level -= 1
            yield "{indent}>".format(  # Делаем отступ и
                indent=" " * self.indent * self.current_level. # Закрываем словарь символом >
            )
        else:
            yield from super().iterencode(o)


mydict = {
    "a": "5",
    "b": {
        "c": "d",
        "e": "f",
        "g": {
            "1": "one",
            "2": "two",
        }
    }
}
print(json.dumps(
    obj=mydict,  # Что сериализуем
    cls=CustomEncoder,  # Кастомный кодировщик
    indent=4,  # Количество пробелов в отступе
))
```

---

Вывод:

```
<
    a: 5,
    b: <
        c: d,
        e: f,
        g: <
            1: one,
            2: two,
        >,
    >,
>
```

---

Для моей задачи работает очень даже хорошо, но будет беда с отступами, если в сериализуемом объекте где-нибудь будет список.